# Declaring Marionette/Backbone Router without unused variable - JSLint

Tags: javascript, variables, backbone.js, marionette, jslint

I'm in a refactoring stage right now, and I'm getting the familiar 'Unused variable' JSLint when declaring and instantiating a Marionette Router. Here is my code:

```
App.Application.addInitializer(function () {

        var globalRouter = new App.Routers.GlobalRouter({
            controller: new App.Controllers.GlobalController()
        });

        //Start Backbone History
        Backbone.history.start();

});
```

The error I get is:

```
 unused 'globalRouter'
```

Basically, I'm using a variable declaration to create the router before I start my app. I'm trying to avoid doing this:

```
       new App.Routers.GlobalRouter({
            controller: new App.Controllers.GlobalController()
        });
```

As it just introduces a different JSLint error, saying 'Do not use 'new' for side effects'. Does anyone have any advice on this?

In addition, I've tried adding:

```
 /*jslint unparam: true */
```

but this does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is debatable, but you could use an IIFE like this:

```
App.Application.addInitializer(function () {
    (function(){
        return new App.Routers.GlobalRouter({
            controller: new App.Controllers.GlobalController()
        });
    }());
});
```

Or use an intermediate variable:

```
App.Application.addInitializer(function () {
    (function(){
        var router = new App.Routers.GlobalRouter({
            controller: new App.Controllers.GlobalController()
        });
        return router;
    }());
});
```

On a side note, since you're refactoring, I would start `history` in an "initialize:after" listener to ensure all routing controller have been initialized before a routing event is triggered.